# Java keeps returning incorrect answer

Tags: java

`a` is the value of the spinner.

```
private void toolCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Integer a = (int) toolSpinner.getValue();

    if (toolEnch.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        double p;
        p = (10 ^ (2 - a) * 13 ^ a);
        double x = Math.round(p);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I am doing `10^(2-a) * 13^a`, and

lets say the spinner is at 1, it returns 6, when it should return 130.

lets say the spinner is at 2, it returns 8, when it should return 169.

I've tested it with WolframAlpha and it gives me the right result. This program however, gives me something way off.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^` is XOR, not exponent.  If you want exponents, use `Math.pow`.

```
p = Math.pow(10, (2-a)) * Math.pow(13, a);
```

Comment: Ah, ok! I thought ^ was exponent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your operations is write in wrong priority,and ^ is XOR not POW,actually you must handle priority's by your self using parenthesis.because parenthesis have high priority more than each operation.
use Math Class
change p variable line like this:

```
p = Math.pow(10, (2-a)) * Math.pow(13, a); // it will be 130.0 in double format when a is 1
```

and if you want calculate anything else like XOR
you must handle periority's by your self in most time's!
like this:

```
 int a = 1;
 double p = 0;
 p = ((10 + (2-a)) * (13 + a));
 System.out.println(p);; // this will be 154.0 in double format.
```

but This:

```
 int a = 1;
 double p = 0;
 p = (10 + (2-a) * (13 + a));
 System.out.println(p); // will print 24.0 in double format.
```